# Vue.js 2 not rendering component

Tags: vuejs2, render

This is my first steps with **Vue JS 2**, and i just trying to load my 'Hello Vue!' component, and I geting no result. =(

**Hello App:** common.js

[image]

**View:** index.pug

[image]

**Result in browser:** Chrome - *the expression did not render in **'Hello Vue!'** =(*

[image]

**Console in browser:** Chrome

[image]

**JS builder:** gulp.babel.js

[image]

Why the expression did not render in **'Hello Vue!'** ?

Comment: Have you tried with "load" instead "DOMContentLoaded"?

Comment: window.onload = function () {...} ? Yes i have

Comment: have you tried import Vue from 'vue' instead of that complicated path. That's how I use it... although.. I use webpack and not gulp.

Comment: Yes i have improve 'Vue' from 'vue' in **gulp.babel.json** on this: `rollupPluginAlias({ 'Vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' })`
In Vue 2 documentation it was look like this: http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/17/0913/h_1505293972_4137241_1c30c14e1f.png

Comment: No I mean replace in common.js
Import vue from "../../node_modules/vue/dist..." with
Import Vue from 'Vue'... the alias you created in your gulp

Comment: Oh yes i have also tried to improve **Vue** from **'Vue'** with *alias* i created in gulp - in that way it could't to find **vue.esm.js** and taking by default from *.package.json* module **vue.runtime.esm.js**

Comment: I'm pretty sure somewhere is stupid misstake, but i didn't find it yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154332/discussion-between-codehacker-and-user3688243).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some recomendation edits, witch U can see below. And it keep to didn't works until I unexpected **rebooted the computer**...

**Hello App:** common.js

[image]

**JS builder:** gulp.babel.js

[image]

**Result in browser:** Chrome - *Now it works =)*

[image]

Thank you @CodeHacker !